# Create one liner (Imperative way) command in kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

Create one liner (Imperative way) command in kubernetes

```
kubectl run test --image=ubuntu:latest --limits="cpu=200m,memory=512Mi" --requests="cpu=200m,memory=512Mi" --privileged=false
```

And also I need to set `securityContext` in one liner, is it possible? basically I need to run container as `securityContext/runAsUser` not as `root` account.

Yes declarative works, but I'm looking for an imperative way.

Comment: Hi, check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37621761/5747959 you can solve this with --overrides

Answer (score 5):

Posting this answer as a community wiki to highlight the fact that the solution was posted in the comments (a link to another answer):

> Hi, check this answer: [stackoverflow.com/a/37621761/5747959](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37621761/5747959) you can solve this with --overrides – CLNRMN 2 days ago

Feel free to edit/expand.

---

Citing `$ kubectl run --help`:

> ```
>   --overrides='': An inline JSON override for the generated object. If this is non-empty, it is used to override the generated object. Requires that the object supply a valid apiVersion field.
> ```

Following on `--overrides` example that have additionals field included and to be more specific to this particular question (`securityContext` wise):

```sh
kubectl run -it ubuntu --rm --overrides='
{
  "apiVersion": "v1",
  "spec": {
    "securityContext": {
      "runAsNonRoot": true,
      "runAsUser": 1000,
      "runAsGroup": 1000,
      "fsGroup": 1000
    },
    "containers": [
      {
        "name": "ubuntu",
        "image": "ubuntu",
        "stdin": true,
        "stdinOnce": true,
        "tty": true,
        "securityContext": {
          "allowPrivilegeEscalation": false
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
' --image=ubuntu --restart=Never -- bash
```

By above override you will use a `securityContext` to constrain your workload.

> Side notes!
>
> - The example above is specific to running a `Pod` that you will exec into (`bash`)
> - The `--overrides` will override the other specified parameters outside of it (for example: `image`)

---

Additional resources:

- *[Kubernetes.io: Docs: Tasks: Configure pod container: Security context](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/security-context/)*
- *[Kubernetes.io: Docs: Concepts: Security: Pod security standards](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/security/pod-security-standards/)*